# ffmpeg crop video from top screen

Tags: ffmpeg

From this

[image]

To this

[image]

My code not working because it's crop from both side (top & bottom)

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter:v "crop=iw:ih-100" -r 0.40 o/output_%04d.jpg
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "scale=960:-1,crop=in_w:in_h-200:0:out_h" -r 0.40 o/output_%06d.jpg
```